# Can I run original MS.Net Framework 4 on Linux someway (with Wine perhaps)?

Tags: .net, linux, mono, wine

I once heard of a guy managed to install original Microsoft .Net Framework on Linux and successfully run Mono-incompatible .Net applications using bleeding-edge MS C# features. Any idea how could he do it?

Comment: I once heard that a guy jumped out of an aircraft at 30K feet, landed in a 1 foot swimming pool and walked away with no injuries.  What you hear about MS .NET on Linux is almost as likely to be true.  The only real option for .NET on Linux is currently Mono.  They are moving towards .NET 4 compatibility but are not there yet.

Comment: thank you for that, i also tried Mono and currently evaluating it in linux, i simply thought that may by .Net Framework can be installed using wine or not that's why the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wine has .NET 2.0 working and sort of has .NET 3.0 working, beyond that and you're out of luck.  Even then I think they're probably spotty at best.  The best support for .NET on Linux is Mono.  Mono has pretty good support for much of the .NET Framework but your still out of luck for .NET 4.  http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: Mono is pretty much fully compatible with .NET 4.0 as of version 2.10 (i think even 2.8 was mostly there)

Answer (score 6):

Actually, .NET 4 has been implemented in Mono.  There just hasn't been a release, which will probably be very soon.  Mono doesn't release beta's due to the fact that you can grab from source.  If you would like to run .NET 4 now, then all you need to do is grab Mono from SVN and build it.  The link that @Mike Cellini gave states it at the bottom.  If you want to start developing or run 4.0 applications against Mono, then this will be your best bet at the moment.  Unless you want to wait for a packaged release.  There's plenty of [documentation](http://mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono) on Mono's site for building from source, which really isn't any different than building a release tarball.

Comment: Mono has: *Everything in .NET 4.0 except WPF, EntityFramework and WF, limited WCF.*

Answer (score 1):

it can only by the Standalone Installer not by the web installer (it is better to try winetricks) or cliсk [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/A/95A9616B-7A37-4AF6-BC36-D6EA96C8DAAE/dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe) for the standalone installer (offline)

Answer (score 0):

This may be of some relevance [dotGnu](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/).