# Can a .Net 5 application that references .Net Framework 4 dlls run on Linux?

Tags: .net, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 web application built on ASP.Net Core.  I know this will run on Linux, because .Net 5 is cross platform compatible, just like .Net Core.  Previous versions of .Net Core could not reference .Net Framework 4.x dlls, but .Net 5 can.

If I add a reference to a .Net Framework 4.x dll from my .Net 5 application, will the .Net 5 web application still run on Linux?  I know this works locally on my Windows machine, but I do not have an easy way to test this on Linux.  Does anyone know what would happen?  I cannot find any articles that touch on this scenario.

Comment: There is no ".NET 4", did you mean ".NET **Framework** 4"? They are *completely* different things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run original MS.Net Framework 4 on Linux someway (with Wine perhaps)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985788/can-i-run-original-ms-net-framework-4-on-linux-someway-with-wine-perhaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be "Yes".  I managed to create a Linux website on Azure and deployed my .Net 5 ASP.Net Core web application to it.  This website displays some text that is only contained in a .Net Framework 4.7 dll.

Honestly, I did not expect this to work.  If anyone can recommend some reading material to explain why this works, I would appreciate it if you would pass it along.